# [08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, openssl, mssql, odbc

I'm trying to connect to an MS SQL Server 2016 from my ubuntu server 22.04.

I've installed the odbc driver following the official MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

The installation works fine and I can connect to newer MS SQL servers, the problem is to connect to 2016 SQL Server, looks like an issue with OpenSSL version. Ubuntu 22.04 uses by default the openssl 3.x.x.

I've enabled some debug options by adding to /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /dev/stdout
```

And the output doesn't help much. I've found some solutions but are always related to old ubuntu.

Here is the output:

```
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.879691][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x55b6b35d3870
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.879839][SQLAllocHandle.c][377]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 2
            Input Handle = 0x55b6b35d3870
        UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'UTF-8' and UNICODE 'UCS-2LE'

[ODBC][62430][1664301799.880405][SQLAllocHandle.c][513]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Output Handle = 0x55b6b35d4590
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.880465][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x55b6b35d4590
            Window Hdl = (nil)
            Str In = [Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxxx,1433;Database=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=**********;][length = 116 (SQL_NTS)]
            Str Out = 0x7fffe858da30
            Str Out Max = 2048
            Str Out Ptr = (nil)
            Completion = 0
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903128][__handles.c][460]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
            Environment = 0x55b6b370ad10
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903245][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][157]
        Entry:
            Environment = 0x55b6b370ad10
            Attribute = 65002
            Value = 0x7fffe8586090
            Buffer Len = 128
            StrLen = 0x7fffe858602c
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903298][SQLGetEnvAttr.c][273]
        Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903319][SQLFreeHandle.c][220]
        Entry:
            Handle Type = 1
            Input Handle = 0x55b6b370ad10
        DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746

        DIAG [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection

[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903893][SQLDriverConnect.c][1637]
        Exit:[SQL_ERROR]
[ODBC][62430][1664301799.903976][SQLError.c][424]
        Entry:
            Connection = 0x55b6b35d4590
            SQLState = 0x7fffe858f046
            Native = 0x7fffe858f040
            Message Text = 0x7fffe858f050
            Buffer Length = 500
            Text Len Ptr = 0x7fffe858f03e
 [08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
[08001][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
```

Also, I've installed the OpenSSL 1.0.1k manually compiling the code, but looking the strace from the isql or sqlcmd it stills using the openssl 3 has you can see here:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

Do you know how to change the libssl from the odbc drive?